# Error while running Grails 2.3.7 app

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I have grails 2.3.7 installed under `C:\Programs Files\Grails\grails-2.3.7`, Created an app, while running it, i got this error below:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files\Grails\grail
s-2.3.7\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: try installing it to the folder which does not contain spaces.

Comment: Any other alternative, Because The directory convention is enforced in the organization

Comment: spaces always mess things up on Windows platform. Try if installing somewhere to C:/Grails solves it or not